# How to custom Coreui dataTable with date range?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, core-ui

I'm using CoreUI admin template with vue js.
I want to custom date range inside datable componen.
Can anyone help me to configure out with this problem?
Anyways, I have found plugin for date range in dataTable

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date == "undefined") {
        aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
        if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
        if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

Comment: Try to add whatever code  you tried to get required in description

Comment: Honestly, I have found plugin for date range of database but, I don't know how to configure out with coreui. Thank for your response!

Comment: and here is the link that I got [https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/filtering/row-based/range_dates.js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of CDataTable with a date range in the docs:

https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/table.html#custom-data-structures-and-filtering-sorting

Comment: Thank for your answer!